# Hibernate 4.3.6+ HikariCP Implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, hikaricp

I am trying to use HikariCP with Hibernate in a maven java ee web app in Netbeans. This is my first time using Hibernate, and I am not using Spring yet as I am not familiar with it but may consider it in the future (please feel free to offer reason why I should adapt it).

In the HikariCP wiki, it mentions that:

> As of Hibernate 4.3.6 there is an official ConnectionProvider class
>   from Hibernate, which should be used instead of the HikariCP
>   implementation. The class is called
>   *org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider.*

It then goes on to describe the configuration for Hibernate 4.x. It talks about the old ConnectionProvider class there however so I am assuming this section is outdated?

I have added the following dependency to my POM.XML file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and with the following properties declared within the  tag in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">testuser</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

I am able to interact with the database as I was before, using the default Hibernate connection pool. Is this all I need to do? Is it now using the HikariCP connection pool? If not what other configuration is required?

If I were to later integrate Spring, how would this affect the HikariCP configuration, or location of the configuration?

Comment: Thats all you need to do re: the hibernate.cfg.xml.  re: Spring, there are a bunch of ways it can probably be done.  Some of the recipes are in the HikariCP wiki and various blogs.

Comment: Unrelated: I would recommed using the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` if you are using a MySQL 5 Database